# Changing an old commit in Git

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

So, I branched my project from the master and made 5 commits to the new branch. Now, I have found out my very first commit is funny: I have added a some changes in some files which I shouldn't have. How can I make this mistake right without messing up the whole thing?

Update: Sorry I explained it wrong as English is not my mother tongue. When you open the Unity editor, some files change automatically. I accidentally committed those files as well. I don't want that. I'd rather get rid of those changes (using *clean*?) and commit the changes I actually made.

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer**: You Can't!

**Long Answer**: Maybe You can!

Every commit in git is dependent on previous commits and all of the commits are in a chain together.. so you can't change a commit without changing all of later commits. (every commit has a ***hash id*** that is dependent to the previous commit)

So the Only way for doing this is to change all of the commits from last commit (HEAD) to that commit. let's suppose we have three commits (commit1, commit2, commit3 == HEAD) and you want to change commit1.

you Have to do this:

```
git reset HEAD~1  // Going back one commit (now HEAD is commit2)
git stash // to keep this commit's changes in stash area
git reset HEAD~1 // Going back one commit (now HEAD is commit1)
(Now doing your changes in commit1)
git add [changed_files]
git commit --amend // Changing first commit
git stash pop // inserting back changes of commit2
git commit -am 'new commit message for commit2'
git stash pop // inserting back changes of commit3
git commit -am 'new commit message for commit3'
```